# How to assign numerical values in one column to text in other column

Tags: r

Basically I'm trying to sort through a large dataset where the first 3 numbers correspond to different texts. Before I can filter through, I'm trying to assign the different strings values.

```
Crops                           101
Fishing                         102
Livestock                       103
Movies, TV, & Stage             201
```

In the larger dataset, there are hundreds of numbers such as 1018347 where the first three numbers correspond to crops and include the number of times that value appeared. The numbers after specify what type of crops, but for the purpose of my work I need to sort through the entire thing by the first three numbers and sum the amount for each time occurred. I'm fairly new to R and wasn't able to find a sufficient answer, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome!  When describing a dataset (`x`), kindly post the output of `dput(x)`, which provides a reproducible example; if `x` has too many rows, then a subset (like `dput(head(x, n = 100))` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i am getting your question correctly but it seems you are looking for a way to first create a new variable based on the first three numbers in the variable and afterwards summarize the results in a sum per category

What could work is

```
data %>% 
mutate(first_part = substr(variable,1,3)) %>%
group_by(first_part) %>%
summarize(occurrences= n())
```

Code above counts the amount of times the "first_part"(which is the first 3 numbers) is occurring. This can also be reproduces for the second part or both together.